# Where did my uncle go?

Tags: cipher, visual, grid-deduction, acrostic, nonogram

> That damned uncle of mine! Running out without telling us has become too commonplace in our house. I did manage to find these two nonograms and a note this time though.
>
> "Fear not nephew! I am going to a place where I will finally be a winner! Don't spend too long on this puzzle, you may have some trouble with your color-blindedness."

Here are the two nonograms I found. Could any of you guys determine where he went?

[image: Nono 1]

[image: Nono 2]

HINT:

> Unlike my last nonogram, the empty end columns weren't necessarily left by accident. Make sure you pay attention to the tags, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Answer

As the educated guess suggested, your uncle is in

> vegas!

Thank you @JGibbers for this beautiful puzzle! :)

## Solution Approach

The two nonograms are

> [image: nono1]
>  [image: nono2]

Refering to the hint of

> color-blindness in the text, we
>
>  1. hint color:
>
>  split the colored nonogram into it's red and blue contributions while interpreting purple squares as both red and blue (as the color purple is a mix of red and blue) to obtain
>  [image: red_nono]
>  [image: blue_nono]
>
>  2. hint blindness:
>
>  and interpret these as Braille gives
>  red: ⠞⠑⠑⠊⠊⠽⠥⠓⠁⠞  = TEEIIYUHAT
>  dropping the first and last column for blue gives
>  blue: ⠓⠅⠽⠎⠝⠕⠗⠑⠗⠂ = HKYSNORER

Thanks to @Deusovi

> these can be read alternatingly (starting with red, then blue, etc.) as
>  THE KEY IS IN YOUR HEART

Taking the tag

> "acrostic" into account, we take the starting letters of each sentence which gives
>  TRIFID
>  This refers to the [trifid cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifid_cipher) with the key "INYOURHEART".
>  Putting in the letters in the trifid cipher by filling one square after another row-wise, we obtain
>  [image: trifid_cipher]
>  where we colored the letters according to the second nonogram. An anagram of these letters gives the solution
>  VEGAS

Comment: You've got the right idea, but your execution on blue is a little off. Added a hint for the second nonogram.

No comment about the educated guess ;)

Comment: @JGibbers I'm really not sure why blue is off... I'm using this [conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII).

Comment: yeah that conversion you're using should be fine, since it's really the last step I don't want to give too much away, but rot13(cnl zber nggragvba gb jurer lbh fgneg.), you'll rot13(raq jvgu n cuenfr) from the first nonogram

Comment: If you alternate reading letters from the red/blue, you get "THE KEY IS IN YOUR HEART".

Comment: rot13 that! @Deusovi (to hide some spoilers). But yeah, the positioning was intentional :)

Comment: Yay! Glad you liked it! I was hoping the type of cipher was obscure enouogh to hide it in an acrostic without immediately giving it away :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm stumped as to what they mean as of yet, but the two nonograms are

> [image]

Comment: Having not looked at this for more than 2 seconds, I wonder if rot13(oenvyyr) would be involved or not.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, @Dorrulf!